# SublimeCodeIntel - how to set path to Python 3 installation

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimecodeintel

I have Python 3.x installation in Windows in "c:\Pyhton3" folder. How can I specify Python folder location for SublimeCodeIntel --so it can find Python 3 source files by "Find declaration" cmd?
What to write in `.codeintel/config` file?

E.g. I want to put caret onto `os.path.isfile` and find source py file - with this id.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SublimeCodeIntel [configuration documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel#configuring) has all the information you need. Basically, an entry like this should work:

```json
{
    "Python3": {
        "python": 'c:/python3/python.exe',
        "pythonExtraPaths": ["c:/python3/lib", "c:/python3/lib/site-packages"]
    }
}
```

Additionally, take a look at `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeCodeIntel -> Settings - Default`. Down at the bottom are some more Python-specific settings:

```json
    "Python": {
        "env": {
            /*
            "PATH": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH",
            "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH"
            */
        }
    }
```

Get rid of the `/* */` comments and change the paths to whatever you want on your Windows system.

Comment: Do you have to set both? In windows there is "C:\Users\MyUser\.codeintel\config" and "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\.codeintel\config" and finally "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.sublime-settings".

Comment: @Romz you have two options - either `C:\Users\MyUser\.codeintel\config` or `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\SublimeCodeIntel.sublime-settings`. You should never modify `.sublime-settings` in the plugin's directory, as if you screw something up you don't have anything to go back on. Instead, copy the file to your `Packages/User` directory and edit it there. I find that easier than using `.codeintel\config`, as the settings file is easily accessed by going to **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeCodeIntel -> Settings - User`**.